# prove that a solution explodes in finite time

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, fundamental-solution

How can I show that the ode
$$
\dot x(t) = t^2x^3 \sin(\frac{1}{t^3x}), x(0)=x_0
$$
doesn't have a unique solution on $[-1,1]$ ?

---

It seems $x\equiv 0$ is a solution.

Now clearly, for $t,x\neq 0$, $g(t,x)=t^2x^3 \sin(\frac{1}{t^3x})$ and $g(t,0)=0=g(0,x)$ is continuous on $(-1,1)\times \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto g(t,x)$ is continuously differentiable, however $g$ is not locally Lipschitz that is for any compact $K\subset (-1,1)\times \mathbb{R}$, we cannot find a constant $L_K$ such that :
$$
|g(t,x)-g(t,y)|\le L_K|x-y|
$$
for all $(t,x), (t,y) \in K$.

I think that for a suitable $x_0$, the solution explodes in finite time but I am struggling to prove it.

Here is the phase portrait.

[image: Graph of (t,x(t))]
we clearly see a blow-up in finite time

Comment: Just to clarify: You are interested in the blow-up of the solution? Or do you want to show uniqueness (like stated in the question)?

Comment: the blow-up of a solution at first

Comment: don't we have $\lim_{t\to 0} g(t,x)=0=g(0,x)$ because $\sin$ is bounded ?

Comment: The time $t_2-t_1$ needed to go from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dx}{v(x)}$, if the right-hand side $v(x)$ did not depend ot $t$. I wonder if you could adapt this somehow to your case.